Compile Sass directly to HTML file with Gulp
I've setup Gulp to compile Sass in VS Code using their guide which works great but I now have a project where I can't embed any external CSS or JS, meaning I would need to get all my compiled Sass into the HTML file into a <style type="text/css">(compiled Sass goes here)</style> preferably also minified. Is there any way of doing this? Currently I have to copy paste the compiled styling manually from my style.css but that is rather cumbersome. Tried searching but couldn't find any solutions.
